# Mongoose Error E11000 duplicate key error index in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) along with [Sails](http://sailsjs.org/). I am making my own `ACL` where my schema consists of a `processName` and its  `subprocesses` which is assigned with different `subprocessName` with different `permissions` namely `READ`,`WRITE`,`ADMIN` and `NA`.

I am unable to save same `subprocess` for different `processName` in my database. I get the following error when I try to do the same which is given below

```
  "name": "MongoError",
  "message": "E11000 duplicate key error index:ACL.processnames.$subprocess.subprocessName_1 dup key: { : \"aaaa\" }",
  "index": 0,
  "code": 11000,
  "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error index: ACL.processnames.$subprocess.subprocessName_1 dup key: { : \"aaaa\" }"
```

My `Schema` which is as follows

```
{
 processName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    subprocess: [{
        subprocessName: {type:String},
        permission: {
            type: String,
            enum: ["READ", "WRITE", "ADMIN","NA"],
            default: "NA"
        }
    }]
}
```

I used `Node Insepector` and found out that my code is failing during the `.save` function execution which is as follows

```
var db = require('../services/db.js'); //DB Connections
var ProcessName = mongoose.model('ProcessName');
var data = {};
data.processName = processName;
data.subprocess = subprocess;
var processes = db.ProcessName(data);
processes.save(processes, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.json({
                        sucess: false,
                        exception: err
                    });
                }
                else {
                return res.json({
                        sucess: true,
                        processDetail: data
                    }); 
                }      
            });
```

My Sample Data for which I am getting the above error when posting it on DHC is given below

```
  {
       "processName":"wessssess LIkes",
       "subprocess":[
                      {"subprocessName":"ssas","permission":"ADMIN"},
                      {"subprocessName":"aaaa","permission":"ADMIN"},
                      {"subprocessName":"aay"}
       ]
  }
```

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to enforce "unique" items within the array. Yes? Indexes are not meant for that. A "unique" index means "across the collection". So no other document can have an array element with that key with the same data. There are different ways to keep individual document arrays unique.

Comment: Hi Blakes Seven, I haven't specified an index or unique parameter constraint on my 'subprocessName' in my 'subprocess'. Mongoose error clearly states that duplicate values are observed on subprocessName.Can you suggest what can be the reason why I am getting this error?

Comment: Yes you do have a uninque index there and that is exactly what the error says `index:ACL.processnames.$subprocess.subprocessName_1`. Run `.getIndicies()` on the collection from the shell. Or better yet, if you do not think you have any indexes then just drop all of them `.dropIndexes()`. If you really are trying to do what I think you are trying then come back and ask that question.

Comment: Hi Blakes Seven I drop all the indexes and deleted my collection.It worked . Thanks for the Help. Can you please post the .dropIndexes as the answer for my future reference?